# AGOL WebMap with Tabs and Layer Control

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

Is it possible in ArcGIS Online to set up a web map that has tabs across the top like the [Story Map Series](http://storymaps-classicqa.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-series/) AND be able to turn on and off layers in the legend as per the [Web App builder approach](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/) and the [Layer List Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-layer-list.htm)?

[image: AGOL Tabs]

I've done some digging on the other templates, but have been unable to find or set up this particular combination.

Comment: Did you try popping the web maps into a basic template app and for adding content to the story use the web page option. Then paste the url to the web app which should look like http://org.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Styler/index.html?appid=randomtextandnumbers

Comment: @RussRoberts Bingo! That does the trick, and using a URL for another map hadn't occurred to me at all. If you're able to expand and post as an answer I'd be happy to accept as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be the template you are looking for.

https://storymaps-classic.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-series/